# SensorEvent with old values

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sensors

I've been trying to retrieve the number of steps taken in an intervall of 30 seconds. I use the `TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` sensor and a custom class which implements the `SensorEventListener` interface. My current implementation looks like this:

```
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StepSensor extends JobService implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "StepSensor";
    public static final Integer JOB_ID = TAG.hashCode();

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor stepSensor;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        logStepInformation();
        return false;
    }

    private void logStepInformation() {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        stepSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, stepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        long milliseconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(event.timestamp, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

        stringBuilder.append("Registered ");
        stringBuilder.append(event.values[0]);
        stringBuilder.append(" steps at ");
        stringBuilder.append(new Date(milliseconds).toString());

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

The class is passed to a `JobScheduler` instance and is being run in the background:

```
    JobScheduler jobSchedulerstepcounter =
            (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobSchedulerstepcounter.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(StepSensor.JOB_ID,
            new ComponentName(this, StepSensor.class))
            .setPeriodic(ParamsLogging.STEPCOUNTER_CONTROL_INTERVAL_MILLIS)
            .build());
```

where

```
public static final long STEPCOUNTER_CONTROL_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 30*1000L;
```

However, it seems that the values stored in the `SensorEvent` are old and the steps taken in that interval don't change:

```
Registered 134.0 steps at Thu Jan 01 23:04:32 MEZ 1970
Registered 134.0 steps at Thu Jan 01 23:05:02 MEZ 1970
Registered 134.0 steps at Thu Jan 01 23:05:32 MEZ 1970
Registered 134.0 steps at Thu Jan 01 23:06:02 MEZ 1970
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onSensorChanged%28android.hardware.SensorEvent%29):

> **NOTE**: The application doesn't own the event object passed as a parameter and therefore cannot hold on to it. The object may be part of an internal pool and may be reused by the framework.

I take it that the `SensorEvent` object passed as a parameter is always the same with an updated timestamp. Is it possible to get the actual number of steps taken when the Event was registered?

I use Android Version 5.0.2.